# Suppose a class object has related properties, is there a better way to initialize than hard-code the relationship?

Tags: javascript

I have a Budget class with an annual, monthly, and weekly property. Is there a better way to do it than below?:

```
class Budget{
    //based on choice, the initializer assigns, then calculates the two other properties
    constructor(value, choice) {
        this.value = value;
        this.choice = choice;
        this.annual = 0;
        this.monthly = 0;
        this.biweekly = 0;
    }

    initialize() {
        this.choice == 1 ? (this.annual = this.value,
                            this.monthly = this.annual/12,
                            this.biweekly = this.annual/52) :
        this.choice == 2 ? (this.monthly = this.value,
                            this.annual = this.monthly*12,
                            this.biweekly = this.annual/52):
        (this.biweekly = this.value,
         this.annual = this.biweekly*52,
         this.monthly = this.annual/12);
                            
    }


}
```

Comment: There's definitely a better way than nested ternary expressions. Everything else is better. How about: https://jsfiddle.net/qwu8bp3r/

Comment: You have a class but you don't have OOP. Put the default initialization in the base class (this class) and the choices in classes that extend it. The property `.choice` is not even needed, the class name should tell what choice is implements.

Comment: You have a class but you don't have OOP. The role of the constructor is to initialize the object, to prepare it to do its job. That means exactly what the method `initialize()` does (and maybe more).

Comment: @ChrisG that is super clever! Much neater than the ternary expressions.

Comment: @axiac Definitely something I will look into. For the current use case I have in mind, I don't think I'll need a whole separate class for each type.

Comment: Depending on who you ask, "biweekly" means either "twice every week" or "every two weeks". In both cases, there are not 52 of them in a year.

Comment: If you don't need classes then don't use classes.